# Number of 5-distinct-digit odd numbers whose tens digit is greater then their hundreds digit.

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find the number of 5-digit (All different, out of the range $[1...9]$, no 0's) odd numbers whose tens digit is greater then their hundreds digit.

My attempt at solving this is to divide into the 5 different options for the unit digit and then further dividing each of these according to possible values the tens-digit can have. This works, but is enormously cumbersome and I get the feeling that a more elegant solution must exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is as follows:

Choose an odd unit digit: $5 \choose 1$

We have $8$ numbers left. Choose any $2$ for the ten and hundred digits: $8 \choose 2$

The order is fixed so the larger number will always go to the ten digit: $1$

Fill in the remaining $2$ digits with the remaining $6$ numbers: ${6 \choose 2} \cdot 2!$

Total numbers of way is thus
$${6 \choose 2} \cdot 2! \cdot {8 \choose 2} \cdot 1 \cdot {5\choose 1} =4200$$